# Error with Firebase database querying

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to simply query the Firebase database inside a table view controller embedded in a tab bar controller.

My data structure is like this:

```
messages
    KO1222_mhm2U6dSC6Kp
        senderDisplayName: "someRandomNameOrEmail"
        senderId: "LfCqpbberPb5doQuFrGHpQDfJSV2"
        text: "ExampleMessage"
    KO12AzTeX_CN8fWDXtI
        senderDisplayName: "someRandomNameOrEmail2"
        senderId: "7S4vEd2IJleIFhuU59aA3G7QETI3"
        text: "To freedom"
    KO12PD47C7NkhAZhW7z
        senderDisplayName: "someRandomNameOrEmail"
        senderId: "LfCqpbberPb5doQuFrGHpQDfJSV2"
        text: "Wow"
etc etc
```

I tried:

```
ref.child("messages").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

     print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
     let enumerator = snapshot.children

     while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
         print(rest.value)
     }
     })
```

in `viewDidLoad` but this gives an error in the table view controller. It works in the normal view controller which is embedded in the same tab bar controller. I get an error that

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Can someone help me to understand how to query the Firebase database in this way? `ref` is not nil; it prints out as `https://my_app_name.firebaseio.com/messages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was actually to do with `var userIds: [String]!` declared at the top of the class. Since it was `nil` prior to the database query it gave an error. The actual code for the database query was fine.